# Replace surrounded text with "**" with multiple characters javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this text:

> Hello! this is ****Some** ** random text that i have to add **html ** format

Some words are surrounded by '**' and i have to replace those with bold html format " < b > " for the first couple of "[asterisk]" and " < / b > " for the final '*'.

i'm not able to search '**' because is a regular expression...

Any suggestions?

Comment: use a backslash to escape the asterisk.

Comment: regex can solve this

Comment: `s.replace(/\*{2}([^*]+)\*{2}/g, '<b>$1</b>');`

Comment: @raina77ow Absolutely! please add the answer to set it as solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
const raw = 'Hello! this is **Some ** random text that i have to add **html ** format';
const tagged = raw.replace(/\*{2}([^*]+)\*{2}/g, '<b>$1</b>');
console.log(tagged);
// Hello! this is <b>Some </b> random text that i have to add <b>html </b> format
```

The trick, as mentioned in comments, is to use backslash to escape the asterisks (those are metacharacters in regex land).

Having said that, I strongly recommend at least considering usage of proper markdown libraries to do markdown stuff AND sanitize your output before injecting it into HTML in one way or another.